# Add New Values ​to Dataframe according to predictions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe called "lastDays":

```
                      Units
Date   
2021-06-01 00:00:00    3
2021-06-01 01:00:00    4
2021-06-01 02:00:00    1
2021-06-01 03:00:00    2
2021-06-01 04:00:00    8
2021-06-01 05:00:00    9
2021-06-01 06:00:00    3
2021-06-01 07:00:00    5
2021-06-01 08:00:00    7
2021-06-01 09:00:00    8
```

I want to integrate the predictions of my model to my dataframe, so I have the following function to add the new values ​​from the last row + 1 of the dataframe:

```
def addNewValue(lastDays,nValues):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(lastDays)):
        lastDays[i] = lastDays[i+1]
    lastDays[lastDays.shift(-1)]=nValues
    return lastDays
```

I want to add the results of my 30-day forecast to the original dataframe "lastDays":

```
steps = 24*20
results=[]
for i in range(7):
    pred = forecaster.predict(steps=steps)
    results.append(pred)
    print(results)
    lastDays=addNewValue(lastDays, results)
```

The error it gives me is `KeyError: 1`  when applying the function lastDays = addNewValue (lastDays, predictions) in the line of the function `lastDays [i] = lastDays [i + 1]`

I may have a basic concept error of applying the i + 1 augmentation or should consider applying a shape, but I need your support to know which option would be the most optimal to be able to add the new values ​​to my original dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! Please see this post on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, we'd need to see the full traceback, as [they're very useful](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) in debugging. Additionally, what is `ultimosDias`? this isn't defined for us so it's hard to know where/how the error is occurring. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution that was the following:

Apply `pd.date-range` to create a new column of dates in the created dataframe "nextMonth" and reflect the forecasts. The applied function `nextMonth['Date'] = pd.date_range (start = lastDays.index [-1], period = len (lastDays), freq = "H")` starts the last day of the original dataframe "lastDays" for append the subsequent hours and days based on the length of the original dataframe, which joins the forecast results from day + 1 of the last date of the dataframe originates "lastDays".

Finally, what I did was apply apend to add the dataframe built with the forecasts "nextMonth" to the original dataframe "lastDays" lastDays.append (nextMonth), obtaining the expected results.

I don't know if it will be the most optimal solution but it is fully functional for me and meets the expectations of my project.